# Renaming files based on the file content in unix

Tags: file, unix, awk, rename

I have a file `filename1.CSV` containing:

```
Number
Date
P3_1.1
P3_3.1
```

And a file `filename2.CSV` containing:

```
Number
Date
Bu1.1
Bu1.2
```

I want the files to be renamed depending on their third line:

`filename1.csv -> filename_p3.csv`
`filename2.csv -> filename_bu1.csv`

Comment: Showing what you've tried so far will increase your chances of getting a helpful response.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

```
for name in filename1.csv filename2.csv; do
  { read line; read line; read line; } < "$name"
  newname="${name/[0-9]*/}_${line/[_.]*/}.csv"
  echo "$newname"
  # mv -i "$name" "$newname"
done
```